# Properties of $T$ so that $f(T)$ is bounded.

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis

Suppose $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$. And define the function $f:A\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ as $$f(\mathbf{a})=\mathbf{a}\cdot(\mathbf{e}_j-\mathbf{e}_i)$$
where $\mathbf{e}_k=(0~0~\cdots~0~1~0~\cdots~0)^t$, the one being in the $k^{th}$ position.
What properties can we assert about $A$, so that $f(A)$ is **bounded**.

Comment: What are i and j? Further your notation with T is not good since a lot of people use T for a linear transformation and write f(T) for f applied on the operator T which can be defined via functional calculie

Comment: @SebastianBechtel $i$ and $j$ are just two positive integers. The rest I edited.

Comment: You fix them once? Then it depends whether $i=j$ (then the map is constantly 0 and hence bounded for all $A$), otherwise $A$ needs to be bounded in both the i-th and j-th component